Debezium MySQL Connector - Incorrect Base64 Encoded Value for Decimal Column
I'm facing an issue with the Debezium MySQL connector where I'm getting incorrect Base64 encoded values for a DECIMAL(10,2) column named Total.
Problem:

In the MySQL database, the Total column has a value of 100.00.
However, in the Debezium change event, I'm receiving a Base64 encoded string JxA= for the Total field.
When I decode this Base64 string, I get a control character instead of the expected numeric value.

What I've tried:

I've ensured that decimal.handling.mode is set to precise in my Debezium configuration.
I'm using the default JSON converters and haven't configured any custom converters for the decimal type.
I've enabled column.propagate.source.type to ensure that the original data types are propagated.
I've checked the Debezium logs for any errors or warnings related to data conversion or serialization, but haven't found anything relevant.

Additional Information:

I'm using the default MySQL configuration for storing dates and times.
The Total column in the database is of type DECIMAL(10,2).
I'm not using any custom transformations or converters that could affect the data before serialization.

I'm not sure what else to try to resolve this issue. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

JxA= is 0x2710 in hex (renders as '\x10) but 10,000 when converted from base64 to base10. Then shift the decimal place by two to get the original column value. Here's python code, but the process should be the same in any language.
import base64
import decimal
byte_string = base64.b64decode("JxA=")
decimal_int = int.from_bytes(byte_string, byteorder='big')
result = decimal.Decimal(decimal_int) / 100  # 100.00


(If somebody knows how to correctly return the data as an integer rather than a b64 string, that's a better solution than this workaround. Also make sure to test that your b64->b10 converter works with negative numbers numbers close to the maximum size of the column)

I was actually curious on how is he getting the base64 encoded in the first place and why
